# How do I properly get the selected index of my select box

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var $article = null;

$('#category').change(function () {
var $categoryName = $("#category").attr('value');

 if ($article == null) {
 $article = $('<h4>Select a business you wish to view.</h4><select id="business" name="business" class="business"></select>').appendTo('.query');
 $("#business").load("php.php", {categoryName:$categoryName});
 }

 });

});
</script>
```

category is the id/class/name given to my select box, Each option is populated through php and is given a value="$row['colName']", I am trying to pass that selected value to a php document on change. So I can pass that value to the next queries WHERE clause.

Can you help me correct the

```
  var $categoryName = $("#category").attr('value');
```

line to get the selected index of #category and the value for w.e option is selected?

here is php.php

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(,,,,);
    // Check connection
    $myVar = $_GET["categoryName"];
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "<option>Failed to connect to the Database</option>" ;
       }
     echo "<option>Select A Business To View Listing</option>";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT BName, Category FROM Business WHERE Category=$myVar");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option class='".$row['BName']."'>".$row['BName']."</option>";
      }
     // Free result set
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: I have always been prone to using $("#category").val() myself

Comment: I tried .val() instead and it is doing the same thing, I wonder if my value is not being passed to the php.php page correctly. Here it is on my server www.masswarveterans.com

Comment: I know its printing php.php because the echo on that page prints the "select a business here" into the options

Comment: what happens when you echo $myVar? in the database is category set up as a string?

Comment: $myVar is nothing until the first select box passes its selected index in a value to the php.php page where $myVar should become w.e is selected

Comment: Your php adds a class equal to the value of the BName field from the database? That seems odd. Perhaps you meant to have it equal `'value="'.$row['BName'].'"'`?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, I am using JQuery to pass the selectedindex value from #category select box to 'php.php' where it takes that value and adds it to the WHERE clause in the query. So if "Food" category is selected it queries Select BName, Category FROM Business WHERE Category='Food'

I just don't know if I am passing this variable from my index.php to php.php correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
var $categoryName = $(this).val();
```

This is the correct way to get the current value of an input element with jQuery.

Comment: so I should be using this not "#category"? does that stay in my script or do I need to add that to the select tag?

Comment: @WorksDone `this` refers to the element being `change`d. So in this case doing `$(this)` is the same as `$("#category")`, except that it won't go looking for any/every element on the page that has `id="category"`. So you can use it just like that in your script without making any changes to your select tag.

Comment: Ok, I understand thank you, I think I'm just having an issue passing that variable to my php.php page now. It seems to be loading php.php and trying to run the query but its like it doesn't know what its looking for. This can be seen on my server @ www.masswarveterans.com, php.php should load into the where clause of the query w.e is selected from that first selectbox on change.

Comment: @WorksDone: It seems you've changed the select box to a search field. I take it you figured it out then?

Comment: Decided to go a different direction, Thank you for all the help, figured it would be better to let people search by location then just do a drop down list of business'